# Contour plot and infinite/indeterminate expressions encountered

Tags: plotting

I need to plot this implicit equation
$$\omega-k=\frac{1}{k}\left[1+\left(1-\frac{\omega}{k}\right) \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{\omega+k}{\omega-k}\right)\right]\,,$$

for $(k,\omega)\in[0,5]\times[0,5]$. Theoretically, the result is finite at $k=0$ (in fact, the limit is $\omega=1$) and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20%5C%5BOmega%5D-k%20%3D%201%2Fk%20%281%20%2B%20%281%20-%20%5C%5BOmega%5D%2Fk%29%201%2F2%20Log%5B%28%5C%5BOmega%5D%20%2B%20k%29%2F%28%5C%5BOmega%5D%20-%20k%29%5D%29) confirms it.

I tried the following piece of code,

```
w[k_, \[Omega]_] := 
  1/k (1 + (1 - \[Omega]/k) 1/2 Log[(\[Omega] + k)/(\[Omega] - k)]);
ContourPlot[{\[Omega] - k == w[k, \[Omega]]}, {k, 0, 
  5}, {\[Omega], 0, 5}]
```

but I get the following error messages:

[image]

and an empty plot. What can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: It is not the limit that cause the issue. Check that for $k=\omega=x$ you have $\log\left(\frac{x+x}{x-x}\right)$

Comment: Thanks, @bmf, but as far as I understand, $k=\omega$ is not a solution to the implicit equation. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

w[k_, ω_] := 1/k (1 + (1 - ω/k) 1/2 Log[(ω + k)/(ω - k)]);

Limit[w[k, ω], #] & /@ {ω -> k, k -> 0, ω -> 0}

(* {1/k, 1/ω, (2 + I π)/(2 k)} *)

w[k_, k_] := 1/k;

w[_?(# == 0 &), ω_] := 1/ω;

w[k_, _?(# == 0 &)] := (2 + I*Pi)/(2 k)

ContourPlot[{ω - k == w[k, ω]}, {k, 0, 5}, {ω, 0, 5},
 Exclusions -> {ω == k},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {k, ω})]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand what I was missing.